# ImageResizer not working after migration from Azure Web App to Plesk hosting

Tags: asp.net, plesk, imageresizer

I have use ImageResizer on my ASP.NET website in Azure. And ImageResizer work's grate.
I move site to Plesk shared hosting. Image resizer stop working correctly. It soesn't create preview of images
[image: No image previw]

resizer.debug.ashx haven't errors

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      dashboard.studlearn.com 9/25/2020 5:41:10 PM
1 Issues detected:
(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.
Assembly use report: 
You are using plugins and assemblies from the V4 Performance Edition.
----------------
License keys
You do not have any license keys installed.
----------------
Registered plugins:
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Image404
ImageResizer.Plugins.SqlReader.SqlReaderPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Storage.BlobProviderBase]
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache]

Configuration:

<resizer>
<clientcache minutes="0" />
<diskcache dir="~/Cache" subfolders="32" enabled="true" autoClean="true" hashModifiedDate="true" />
<plugins>
<add name="Image404" />
<add name="SqlReader" connectionString="[redacted]" prefix="~/images/files/previews/" idType="Int" blobQuery="select Preview from UserFilePreview where UserFileId = @id" modifiedQuery="Select UserFileId From UserFilePreview WHERE UserFileId=@id" existsQuery="Select COUNT(UserFileId) From UserFilePreview WHERE UserFileId=@id" requireImageExtension="false" cacheUnmodifiedFiles="true" />
<add name="DiskCache" />
</plugins>
<image404 default="~/images/default/nopreview2.jpg" />
<diagnostics enableFor="allhosts" />
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, 404, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/10.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.42000
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of ImageResizer are you using? What error message do you get when you visit the image URL directly?

Comment: Error 404. Version 4.0.4

Comment: Try a modern version of ImageResizer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to using a very old version of ImageResizer. If the problem persists after upgrading to the latest version, please share the new diagnostics page so we can help.